# Transfer HIVE tables between two cloudera hadoop clusters using Sqoop import/export service.

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop, sqoop, sqoop2

Is there a way to use Sqoop service to import/export data between two hadoop clusters. Following sqoop command(from cluster1 master node to cluster2 master node) is not working for me.

> sqoop list-databases --connect "jdbc:hive2://172.11.21.17:10000/default"

I know that Distcp is the solution for transfering data between Hadoop clusters. But I dont want go with Distcp service as it require many ports to be open between two cluster servers.

I got some help from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31502364/sqoop-import-from-hive-to-hive) but it did not help much.

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think that `sqoop` does not use the same exact ports that ` hadoop distcp` uses? In both cases there is a YARN job spawn to read and/or write to HDFS. In a distributed way.

Comment: Hi Samson,  I am building sqoop jdbc connection. But Hadoop distcp require namenode url.